# How to retain HTML styles after conversion to docx with Pandoc

Tags: pandoc

I have an html file that goes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {text-align:center;}
p {text-align:center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My heading</h1>
<p>Some poetry here.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

And I want to convert it to docx in pandoc. I tried with the usual command

> pandoc -s test.html -o test.docx

And the text is correctly rendered, but it is not centered. I am automatically generating hundreds of htmls so a manual fix isn't in the budget. Basically I need to have some paragraphs left-aligned (the default) and some centered, since they are poetry. How can this be achieved?

Thank you.

PS: I could also use markdown as the input language instead of Html.

Comment: pandoc doesn't deal with styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to customize a docx template and apply the template when converting HTML into docx. In your case, `<h1>` is converted into `Heading 1` in Word, and `<p>` is converted into `First Paragraph`.

Steps:

1. Create a docx template.

   `pandoc -o custom-reference.docx --print-default-data-file reference.docx`
2. Open `custom-reference.docx` and modify Styles.

   1. Center `Heading 1`
   2. Center `First Paragraph`
3. Save `custom-reference.docx`
4. Convert.

   `pandoc input.html -o output.docx --reference-doc custom-reference.docx`